# Socket Programming Python

Tags: sockets, python-2.7, networking

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('localhost', 8021))
s.listen(10)

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'got connected from', addr
    s.send("sending to client")
    conn.close()
    s.close()
```

The problem is as soon i run my client code, it shows `"got connected from ('127.0.0.1', 52764)"`  but then it shows the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\server", line 13, in <module>
    s.send("sending to client")
error: [Errno 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

How can I correct it?

My client code is:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = 'localhost'
port = 8021


s.connect((host, port))

revieved = s.recv(1024)
print "Recieved: ", recieved
```

Comment: Is there anything unclear with my answer, or any other reason why you didn't mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer is simple and I may snag some reputation here!

You are confusing your general socket with the specific client connection. What you receive from running s.accept() is a tuple which consists of: remote socket connection object and remote socket address. This way you can speak to specific client, by referring to the right connection object.

So the fixed could looks like this:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('localhost', 8021))
s.listen(10)

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'got connected from', addr
    conn.send("sending to client")
    conn.close()
    s.close()
```

Assuming that everything else is working fine!